# Streaming from AWS S3 fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, debian-stretch

I am trying to download a large (750GB) tar file from S3:

```
$ /usr/bin/aws s3 cp s3://something.db.backup/dbbackup.tar.gz - | tar zxvf -
```

This runs for a long time (>4 hours), then fails, with eg.:

```
download failed: s3://something.db.backup/dbbackup.tar.gz to - I/O operation on closed file.
```

I'm now running this with `--debug`, which it will presumably do for a very long time still. In the meantime, any idea what might be the problem? My own thought is that I could get this error if `tar` dies, or if the network connection dies. I think it is unlikely that `tar` would go away, but on the other hand, wouldn't a lost network connection give a different error? Any thoughts?

Comment: We would try to rerun the One-Liner without the `- | tar zxvf -` Suffix, if the offline storage space affords the accommodation for both the archive and for its contents, @j4nd3r53n.

Comment: not really, but it may be worth doing just to see if it is the connection to s3 that fails. I'll see where the debug run goes first.

Comment: Long and Tedious Processes with Huge Amount of Data. We would attempt to find on the Internet similar situations related both to the "_I/O operation on closed file_" Error Message and to the _S3_ Environment. At the first glance, nothing similar has popped up yet.

Comment: Believe you me, if I could avoid the long and tedious process, I would :-)

Comment: Try to come up with a better BackUp-and-Restore Plan Document, @j4nd3r53n. Our recent adventures with Data up to around 920 Giga-Bytes in size have been extremely unpleasant. Smaller chunks of Data - let us say, up to less than 150 Giga-Bytes - are easier to digest. Study the _S3_ Environment, see how it is made up and consequently attempt to _Divide-et-Impera_. That is, avoid ruling the whole empire at once.